Runtime.UserCodeSyntaxError when running a docker container containing playwright in AWS Lambda
I  created a dockerfile containing the dependencies needed to scrape websites in AWS lambda. However I am getting this error when running. Building and pushing the dockerfile yielded no errors, only when I am executing the code in the Lambda terminal does the error show up. What is the cause of the error and how can I remedy it?
Error
{
  "errorMessage": "Syntax error in module 'lambda_function': invalid syntax (base_events.py, line 296)",
  "errorType": "Runtime.UserCodeSyntaxError",
  "requestId": "",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/function/asyncio/base_events.py\" Line 296\n            future = tasks.async(future, loop=self)\n"
  ]
}

My dockerfile is as follows
# # Define function directory
ARG FUNCTION_DIR="/function"

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/playwright/python:v1.49.0-noble as build-image


# Install aws-lambda-cpp build dependencies
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
    g++ \
    make \
    cmake \
    unzip \
    libcurl4-openssl-dev

# Include global arg in this stage of the build
ARG FUNCTION_DIR
# Create function directory
RUN mkdir -p ${FUNCTION_DIR}

# Copy function code
COPY . ${FUNCTION_DIR}


# Install the runtime interface client
RUN pip3 install  \
    --target ${FUNCTION_DIR} \
    -r /function/requirements.txt


# Multi-stage build: grab a fresh copy of the base image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/playwright/python:v1.49.0-noble

# Include global arg in this stage of the build
ARG FUNCTION_DIR
# Set working directory to function root directory
WORKDIR ${FUNCTION_DIR}

# Copy in the build image dependencies
COPY --from=build-image ${FUNCTION_DIR} ${FUNCTION_DIR}


ENTRYPOINT [ "/usr/bin/python", "-m", "awslambdaric" ]
CMD [ "lambda_function.handler" ]


My requirements.txt file is as follows
asyncio==3.4.3
awslambdaric==2.2.1
boto3==1.35.49
botocore==1.35.49
certifi==2024.8.30
charset-normalizer==3.4.0
colorama==0.4.6
exceptiongroup==1.2.2
greenlet==3.1.1
idna==3.10
iniconfig==2.0.0
jmespath==1.0.1
packaging==24.1
playwright==1.49.0
pluggy==1.5.0
pyee==12.0.0
pytest==8.3.3
pytest-base-url==2.1.0
pytest-playwright==0.5.2
python-dateutil==2.9.0.post0
python-slugify==8.0.4
requests==2.32.3
s3transfer==0.10.3
simplejson==3.19.3
six==1.16.0
text-unidecode==1.3
tomli==2.0.2
typing_extensions==4.12.2
urllib3==2.2.3
websockets==10.1

Lastly, I am using a very simple synchronous request using playwright in python, my lambda_function.py is as follows
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright


def handler(event, context):
    
    with sync_playwright() as p:
        browser = p.chromium.launch(headless=True)
        page = browser.new_page()
        page.goto("http://example.com/")
        browser.close()
        return("finished")

I found a similar article regarding this issue however none of the solutions helped.
